# What is absolute unique visitor in classical analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have been coming across this term "Absolute Unique user". I can not find this in Google (Classical) Analytics. 
The closest definition I could find is [this](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/absolute_unique_visitor.html).

Is this a newly added metric in Universal Analytics? If so how can I find out "Absolute Unique user" via Google Analytics?

How is different than "Unique Visitor"?

Also I found [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/google-analytics-absolute-unique-visitors-report.html) but for the life of me, I can not find this report. Is it a paid thing?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know on this [here](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/07/30/absolute-unique-unique-visitors-google-analytics/)...

Past [study](http://www.academia.edu/4492127/How_Google_Analytics_and_Conventional_Cookie_Tracking_Techniques_Overestimate_Unique_Visitors) on how Google Analytics measure unique visitors.

Absolute Unique Visitors was removed from Google Analytics some time ago now...

Comment: so how can i calculate new "visitor"? because in classical analytics it shows new visits.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? New visits are exactly that, [new visitors to your website that haven't got an active GA  _utmb cookie set](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en-GB).